# Error when creating a new text file with python?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, file-io

This function doesn't work and raises an error. Do I need to change any arguments or parameters?

```
import sys

def write():
    print('Creating new text file') 

    name = input('Enter name of text file: ')+'.txt'  # Name of text file coerced with +.txt

    try:
        file = open(name,'r+')   # Trying to create a new file or open one
        file.close()

    except:
        print('Something went wrong! Can\'t tell what?')
        sys.exit(0) # quit Python

write()
```

Comment: When writing a question, always be sure to state *what* doesn't work. Is there a syntax error? Does it crash? Does it do something, but not what you intended? Ideally, give us the expected outcome and the actual outcome. "Doesn't work" is too vague.

Comment: Get rid of that harmful "exception handling" block that only prevents you from knowing exactly what went wrong.

Comment: +1 @brunodesthuilliers ! What he means is don't write such generic except blocks. If you are unsure what exceptions are, remove the exception handling and test, you will at least know what's going wrong.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does open() even do? I've read the answers below and got it working, although I chose to go with 'a+' rather than 'r+' simply because I have a record keeping application in mind. But now that it's working, how do I actually append data? And where exactly is the file I'm creating? ---To specify what 'working' means, I receive as output the following line: `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='hello' mode='a+' encoding='cp1252'>`

Answer (score 114, accepted):

If the file does not exists, `open(name,'r+')` will fail.

You can use `open(name, 'w')`, which creates the file if the file does not exist, but it will truncate the existing file.

Alternatively, you can use `open(name, 'a')`; this will create the file if the file does not exist, but will not truncate the existing file.

Comment: Neither "w" or "a" creates a new file for me.

Comment: Stupid me didn't add the directory Desktop in my path, so I was sitting there missing a part of the file path. . .

Comment: to avoid modifying an existing file, `'x'` could be used instead of `'w'`, `'a'`.

Answer (score 6):

instead of using try-except blocks, you could use, if else

this will not execute if the file is non-existent,
    open(name,'r+')

```
if os.path.exists('location\filename.txt'):
    print "File exists"

else:
   open("location\filename.txt", 'w')
```

'w' creates a file if its non-exis

Answer (score 6):

following script will use to create any kind of file, with user input as extension

```
import sys
def create():
    print("creating new  file")
    name=raw_input ("enter the name of file:")
    extension=raw_input ("enter extension of file:")
    try:
        name=name+"."+extension
        file=open(name,'a')

        file.close()
    except:
            print("error occured")
            sys.exit(0)

create()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but sadly doesn't work for me as "error occurred"!!

Comment: Not following PEP. Using different indentation. Incorrectly handling exception.

Answer (score 3):

This works just fine, but instead of

```
name = input('Enter name of text file: ')+'.txt'
```

you should use

```
name = raw_input('Enter name of text file: ')+'.txt'
```

along with

```
open(name,'a') or open(name,'w')
```

Comment: The question is marked as `python-3.x` in which `raw_input` is not available.

Comment: Tag `python-3.x` was added after this answer

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys

def write():
    print('Creating new text file') 

    name = raw_input('Enter name of text file: ')+'.txt'  # Name of text file coerced with +.txt

    try:
        file = open(name,'a')   # Trying to create a new file or open one
        file.close()

    except:
        print('Something went wrong! Can\'t tell what?')
        sys.exit(0) # quit Python

write()
```

this will work promise :)

Comment: Does this add anything that didn't already exist in the 2 year old answers above?

Comment: He changed `name=input()` to `name=raw_input()`. Of course, that's deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can os.system function for simplicity :

```
import os
os.system("touch filename.extension")
```

This invokes system terminal to accomplish the task.

Comment: one of the best things about python is the stdlib abstracts away OS specific utility calls such as touch... best to avoid something like this at all costs

Answer (score 0):

You can use `open(name, 'a')`

However, when you enter filename, use inverted commas on both sides, otherwise `".txt"`cannot be added to filename

Comment: it looks like the previous answer already mentioned open(name, 'a'), so it would have been better to just add your last line as a comment

Comment: "Inverted commas"? Do you mean *single quotes*? Python doesn't care whether you enclose a string in single quotes or double quotes. It only matters if the string includes a matching delimiter; enclosing it in the other kind can save having to escape the enclosed character.