# Using raw_input() to create the filename

Tags: python

I'm new to coding, and I'm trying to write code to let someone create and name a new text document. However, I have no idea how to do this.

I need help on how to use `raw_input()` to name a file. E.g., if the user enters 'dog', it will create a new .txt file called 'dog.txt'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533621/creating-a-new-text-file-with-python

Answer (score 1):

```
name = raw_input('Enter name of text file: ')+'.txt'
```

Alone with

```
open(name,'a') or open(name,'w')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
file_name = raw_input("Please enter a name:")
new_file = open(file_name + ".txt", "w")
new_file.close()
```

Those 3 lines will -

1. Read input from the user.
2. Open a file for writing ("w" flag) with the given name
3. Close the file (empty as we didn't write anything to it).