# Simply create a file in a windows directory using Python

Tags: python-2.7

All I want to do is create a file (doesn't matter the extension) in a windows directory using Python.

I cannot find any reference to this specific function anywhere currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open(filename, "w")` might be what you're looking for. The `"w"` argument means write and will create that file if it doesnt already exist. If it does exist, it will overwrite the contents if written to. [Python I/O Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: THIS IS IT - THANK YOU!!!!!  Waiting the 10 min so I can make sure I mark this as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You would use write() for this, using a file name that you haven't used before.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_write.htm

Comment: a better explanation is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18533621/creating-a-new-text-file-with-python